# Delphi 7 BASE64 function to make a showable <img src="data: image/jpg; data, xxxx -/> string

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to make this function in Delphi7

```
Function CreateBase64String(FileName:String):Base64String;
```

Have tried INDY 6-7 and 9 - but INDY (6-7--9) gives me nothing but errors. Don't know why.

After a lot of trouble I have finally made this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Dialogs, ExtDlgs, StdCtrls, Jpeg;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    select: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    ToB64: TButton;
    OpenPictureDialog1: TOpenPictureDialog;
    DecBtn: TButton;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ToB64Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure selectClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DecBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1  : TForm1;
  Curdir : string;

implementation

Uses
   EncdDeCd;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Curdir := ExtractfileDir(Application.ExeName);
end;

procedure TForm1.ToB64Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   instream, oustream :  TMemoryStream;
begin
   instream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   instream.LoadFromFile(Edit1.text);
   oustream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   EncodeStream(instream,oustream);
   instream.Free;
   oustream.SaveToFile(Edit2.Text);
   oustream.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.selectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Edit1.Text := '';
   if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then
      begin
         Edit1.Text := OpenPictureDialog1.FileName;
         Edit2.Text := ChangeFileExt(Edit1.Text,'.b64');
      end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DecBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   instream, oustream : TMemoryStream;
   s                  : string;
begin
   instream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   instream.LoadFromFile(Edit2.text); //b64 file
   oustream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   DecodeStream(instream,oustream);
   instream.Free;
   s := Edit1.Text;
   insert('x',s,pos('.',s));        // sæt et 'X' på org filen
   oustream.SaveToFile(s);
   oustream.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR
   Ofile : TextFile;
   ifile : TextFile;
   Istr  : string;
begin
   Edit1.Text := Curdir + '\sunset.jpg';
   Edit2.Text := Curdir + '\sunset.b64';
   ToB64Click(NIL);
   AssignFile(Ofile,curdir + '\TESTABCDEF.HTML');
   Rewrite(ofile);
   Writeln(ofile,'<HTML><BODY>');
   Write(ofile,'<img src="DATA:IMAGE/JPG; base64,');
   Assignfile(ifile,edit2.Text);
   Reset(ifile);
   While not Eof(Ifile) DO
      BEGIN
         Readln(Ifile,Istr);
         Write(ofile,Istr);
      END;
   Closefile(ifile);
   Writeln(ofile, '" height="100" width="100" />');
   Writeln(Ofile,'</body></html>');
   Closefile(ofile);
   DecBtnClick(NIL);
end;

END.
```

But no matter what I do, the OFILE (TESTABCDEF.HTML) don't show up correctly in my webbrowsers (Firefox and IE8).

The AssignFile-stuff is for test purposes only. Normally I use Streams.

Tried big JPEG's --> Error
Tried small JPEG's --> Error!

Can anybody tell me What I'm doing wrong?

Kris / Norway

Comment: "gives me nothing but errors" and "--> Error!" are not problem descriptions. What specific errors do you get? (And switching from streams to AssignFile is nonsense "for test purposes". Changing from the proper way to do things to antiquated means doesn't enhance testing.)

Comment: I tested your code. If I ignore the structure and the lack of error handling I noticed that you have `height="100" width="100"`. This will limit the size of the displayed image to 100 x 100. I am guessing you wanted to put 100% instead of 100. If that's your problem the it would really help if you mentioned that instead of just saying "don't show up correctly in my webbrowsers".

Comment: To Ken White:  I agree. Next timwe I'll do it the rigt way - even in testing. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: To Graymatter: First I tried without the height and width - and the result was (still) negative. I have bad experience with IE's (some older IE's NEED width and Height in the <img tag .. to show images), so I thought this might be the error - but I was wrong. Problem still exists. With or without "height and width". It shows the characteristic square in IE-8 (and Firefox) but no picture at all.

Comment: To Graymatter:  Did you get a picture (anything?) on your IE or FF ?

Comment: If you want someone to get notified of your message then add their name after an @ symbol at the start like this @KRIS-Norway - Using your code I was able to display the images fine (XE2). In IE there is a limitation on the size of the image that can be embedded. It's something like 32k. In firefox it worked fine. You can try and change it to JPEG instead of JPG but both worked for me. One of the best ways to get help is to add a SCCEE. Thats a block of code that people can copy and run immediately. Normally it's a console application as that's the quickest.

Comment: Base64 encodes binary input to text output. It does not encode text to text.

Answer (score 1):

Indy's base64 encoder works just fine, you probably just are not using it correctly.

```
Uses
  ..., IdCoderMIME;

Function CreateBase64String(FileName: String): String; 
var
  Fs: TFileStream;
begin
  Fs := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
  try
    Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(Fs);
  finally
    Fs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ofile : TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile(Ofile,curdir + '\TESTABCDEF.HTML');
  Rewrite(ofile);
  Writeln(ofile,'<HTML><BODY>');
  Write(ofile,'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,');
  Write(ofile, CreateBase64String(Curdir + '\sunset.jpg'));
  Writeln(ofile, '" height="100" width="100" />');
  Writeln(Ofile,'</body></html>');
  Closefile(ofile);
end;
```

I would even go as far as getting rid of the `TextFile` and use a `TFileStream` instead, so that Indy can write its base64 output directly to your target file and not waste memory putting it in a `String` first:

```
Uses
  ..., IdCoderMIME;

procedure WriteBase64String(ADest: TStream; FileName: String);
var
  Fs: TFileStream;
begin
  Fs := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
  try
    TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(Fs, ADest);
  finally
    Fs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ofile : TFileStream;
begin
  Ofile := TFileStream.Create(curdir + '\TESTABCDEF.HTML', fmCreate);
  try
    // WriteStringToStream() is an Indy function...
    WriteStringToStream(Ofile, '<HTML><BODY>'+EOL);
    WriteStringToString(Ofile, '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,');
    WriteBase64String(Ofile, Curdir + '\sunset.jpg');
    WriteStringToStream(Ofile, '" height="100" width="100" />'+EOL);
    WriteStringToStream(Ofile, '</body></html>'+EOL);
  finally
    Ofile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: After the Last input (not the one by Remy Lebeau) I searched the Cyberspace for Base64encoded files. Ran my program on one of the pic's. Compared files with the orignal. There were differences. Changed EnCdDecd to jvCMime.  And Ran again. Files were identical now. But still would not show correctly in IE (of FF). Examined IE-version (FF too) -- (OOOOOOPS - much to old - both) . Upgraded then FF and IE and ran again. And Heureka It worked. Now I can use it as my intensions were. I deeply apologize for this question, when the error(s) are in my own code / machine. Deeply sorry.

Comment: To Remy Lebeau:  Thanks for the Code. I'll try it and implement it (much smarter than mine .. ) But in delphi (read INDY) I am still a novice... Thanks a lot... Kris